In Ant Design (ng-zorro) "the icon cloud-upload-o does not exist or is not registered" using module federation and an HTTP interceptor
We're using module federation and Angular 16. We load ng-zorro icons in the host application and in the microfrontends, both of which load ng-zorro (v16).
    <button *ngIf="primaryButton"
        nz-button
        nzType="primary"
        (click)="primaryButton.action()"
        class="x-header-button-primary"
        [disabled]="primaryButton.disabled">
      <i *ngIf="primaryButton.nzIconName"
          nz-icon
          [nzType]="primaryButton.nzIconName"></i>
      {{ primaryButton?.text }}
    </button>

This was working fine, and the icons were displaying inside the buttons.
This is the HTML created by ng-zorro:
  <button nz-button nztype="primary" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ng-star-inserted">
    <i nz-icon="" class="anticon anticon-plus ng-star-inserted">
      <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" fill="currentColor" width="1em" height="1em" data-icon="plus" aria-hidden="true"><defs><style></style></defs><path d="M482 152h60q8 0 8 8v704q0 8-8 8h-60q-8 0-8-8V160q0-8 8-8z"></path><path d="M176 474h672q8 0 8 8v60q0 8-8 8H176q-8 0-8-8v-60q0-8 8-8z"></path>
      </svg>
    </i>
    <span class="ng-star-inserted"> Add Vehicle </span>
  </button>

Then we added an HTTP Interceptor as a provider inside NgModule to catch HTTP errors in the application, and then suddenly our icons no longer load and we see console errors:
Uncaught Error: [@ant-design/icons-angular]:the icon cloud-upload-o does not exist or is not registered.
    at IconNotFoundError (ant-design-icons-angular.mjs:93:12)

If we remove the HTTP interceptor in the host application, the issue is resolved.
The HTTP interceptor in the microfrontend doesn't seem to cause any issues.
It seems that once the HTTP interceptor is there, ng-zorro attempts an HTTP GET request to get the icon, and that fails.
Why would adding an Interceptor throw off the loading of ng-zorro icons?
